# react native touch function can not response well

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When a View cover another View, the TouchableOpacity can not response well.

When I press the View, it should alert message. But it can not response well, sometime it does not alert message.

This demo work well in simulator, just do not work well in device.

[image: demo]

[Here is the full code : https://github.com/kk412027247/swipe_multiple_card](https://github.com/kk412027247/swipe_multiple_card)

Need helps, many thanks.

```
export default class Card extends React.Component{
    translateX = new Animated.Value(0);
    _panResponder = PanResponder.create({
        onMoveShouldSetResponderCapture: () => Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 
        this.props.zIndex ===3 : this.props.zIndex === 1,
        onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 
        this.props.zIndex ===3 : this.props.zIndex === 1,
        onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([null,{dx: this.translateX}]),
        onPanResponderRelease: (e, {vx, dx}) => {
            const screenWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;
            if (vx >= 0.5 || dx >= 0.5 * screenWidth) {
                this.props.forward();
                Animated.timing(this.translateX, {
                    toValue: 0,
                    duration: 200
                }).start();
            } else if(vx <= -0.5 || dx <= -0.5 * screenWidth){
                this.props.backward();
                Animated.timing(this.translateX, {
                    toValue: 0,
                    duration: 200
                }).start();
            } else {
                Animated.spring(this.translateX, {
                    toValue: 0,
                    bounciness: 10
                }).start();
            }
        }
    });


render(){
const {title,content, top, left, zIndex, elevation, backgroundColor,scale} = this.props;
const _style = [
  styles.container, {
    top,
    left,
    zIndex,
    elevation,
    backgroundColor,
    transform:[
      // {scale:scale},
      {translateX: this.translateX}
    ]
  }
];
return(

    <Animated.View
      style={_style}
      {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}
    >
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.button}
        onPress={alert.bind(null, title)}
      >
        <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
        <Text>{content}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

    </Animated.View>


    )
  }
}
```

Comment: You may get better responses if you include the relevant code in your question instead of a GitHub link. Also could you tell us what debugging you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I find the answer myself.
`Because PanResponder capture the event, button can not respond the touch event.`
To fix this problem, if finger move is short, wen can ignore it.
For example, we can ignore the action if the finger mover is less then 5px.
Now button will respond the touch event.

```
onMoveShouldSetPanResponder:(evt, gestureState) => {
    const { moveX, moveY, dx, dy } = gestureState
    if( dx > 5 || dy > 5) {
        return true
    }else {
        return false
    }

}
```

**Now button will respond the touch event.**

I find the answer from [here](https://codedaily.io/tutorials/1/Maintain-Touchable-Items-with-a-Parent-PanResponder-in-React-Native).